# React Native Tab View inactive tab background color

Tags: react-native, react-native-tab-view

I am currently using react-native-tab-view (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) to implement tabs on my app react Native app.

I am struggling to change the background color of the inactive tab items? Has anyone done this before or have any ideas ?

I saw an example of someone using the renderLabel function to change the color of the text color of the inactive tab. It's almost like I need to be looking for a renderView function or something?

Comment: There is something call renderIndicator, could that maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: @SebbeBerglönn no, the indicator is like the line under the selected tab